# Remove decimal vales from y axis in achartengine graph android

Tags: android, achartengine

I wanna remove decimal number on Y axis in achartengine graph library as shown below :

[image]

CODE :

```
public GraphicalView createIntent(List<double[]> values, float height_) {

        height_ = (float) (height_ + 0.4);

        String[] titles = new String[] { "Assignments" };

        int[] colors = new int[] { getResources().getColor(
                R.color.color_ff83ba20) };

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

        if (height_ < 0)
            height_ = 1;
        setChartSettings(renderer, " ", " ", " ", 0, 5, 0, height_,
                Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setXLabels(0);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 50, 50, 10, 10 });


        renderer.setInScroll(true); // for inscoroll

        renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        renderer.setSelectableBuffer(100); // for fixed chart

        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer
                    .getSeriesRendererAt(i);

            // seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        }

        final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getActivity(),
                buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer, Type.STACKED);
        return grfv;
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(13);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(13);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(13);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(0.6);
        renderer.setShowGridX(true);
        renderer.setShowGridY(true);
        renderer.setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_0dffffff));

        renderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_eeeded));

        renderer.setXLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.color_black));
        renderer.setBarWidth(60);
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);

        renderer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.color_fbfbfc));

        renderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_fbfbfc));

        renderer.setInScroll(true); // for inscoroll

        renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        renderer.setSelectableBuffer(100); // for fixed chart

        int length = colors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(colors[i]);

            r.setChartValuesSpacing(15);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles,
            List<double[]> values) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
            double[] v = values.get(i);
            int seriesLength = v.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add(v[k]);
                // series.add(v[k]);
            }

            XYSeries d = series.toXYSeries();

            if (values.get(i)[0] > 0)
                d.addAnnotation((int) (values.get(i)[0]) + "", 1,
                        values.get(i)[0] + 0.05);
            if (values.get(i)[1] > 0)
                d.addAnnotation((int) (values.get(i)[1]) + "", 2,
                        values.get(i)[1] + 0.05);
            if (values.get(i)[2] > 0)
                d.addAnnotation((int) (values.get(i)[2]) + "", 3,
                        values.get(i)[2] + 0.05);
            if (values.get(i)[3] > 0)
                d.addAnnotation((int) (values.get(i)[3]) + "", 4,
                        values.get(i)[3] + 0.05);

            // d.addAnnotation("hi", 3.4, 5);
            // d.addAnnotation("hi", 4.4, 4);

            dataset.addSeries(d);
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer,
            String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin,
            double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
            int labelsColor) {
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 10, 65, 10, 0 });
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setInScroll(true); // for inscoroll

        renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        renderer.setSelectableBuffer(100); // for fixed chart

    }
```

I want Y axis to show complete Integer numbers only ,
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: my Y-axis values are dynamically generated

Comment: why you dot think to convert that to integer?

Comment: yes i want that but incase of 0.7 it will comvert to 0 and i dont what that 0 to display

Comment: what you are expecting set in that case ?

Comment: just set condition than if value is greater than 0.5 than integer value should be 1 or as u want.

Comment: @Achilles u mean change in native code of achartengine?

Comment: no, am talking about Y axis value. if its value 0.5 or greater than take integer value 1 and set it on graph rather than 0.

Comment: @Achilles you mean in the creation of the value is it ?

Comment: @Achilles i cannot do that that will complate look my graph so bad , i just wanna avoid decimal values to diaply

Comment: ok tell me what you want to display if value will be 0.5?

Comment: @Sreekanthss i m not creating that each values , that is done by achartengin i can just give max height as like in above its 2 in y axis\

Comment: @Achilles i dont wanna diplay decimal values like 0.1 ...0.6....0.7...0.x ...just complate integer number 1 ..2 ....5 .... 9....

Comment: really you are confusing all of us

Comment: @Sreekanthss what can i do for making u understand, this is what i need http://i.stack.imgur.com/D34td.png

Comment: ok  understand your requirement, you wan hide that coordinate if it is  decimal right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axis values are dynamically generated based on the range values.

One solution could be to just remove the default labels and add custom ones like this:

```
 renderer.addYTextLabel(y, y + "");
```

where y is an integer value.

Comment: one more question is i want to draw annotaion in middle of bar ..but when i make label color white its not visible ...and when i make black its bit visible ...not i need strongly visible in middle of bar that is grenn color as seen above in question ...the labels 2,2,1 i want to shoe in middle of green bar with white color plz help..

Comment: can u plz help me on this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749304/radius-of-doughnut-chart-in-achartengine